# Multiple calendars in Outlook, without breaking invitations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

For whatever legacy reason, people in my workplace send out invitations in outlook to everyone in the office as their means of scheduling time off (or out of the building).  I want to have a record of these, so I know who is where, but I don't want to clutter up my primary Outlook calendar with them.

The solution I've been using for a while now is to have a secondary calendar and to move all these invitations to that calendar.  Then, I can show/hide that one as necessary.  The problem with this, however, is that I get "This meeting is not in the calendar" warnings when looking at the invitation, and if they update/delete the invitation, it can't find the correct event to modify.

Is there any way to make Outlook aware of the events that have moved to the secondary calendar?

---

I was using Outlook 2003, although I just upgraded to 2010.  Email accounts are via Exchange 2010.

Comment: We use a Shared Time Off Calendar on our Exchange Server. Everyone can view it, if they choose, but it doesn't cluttering your personal calendar. Check with your administrator to see if they could set one up.

Comment: I've suggested that before, but corporate culture is hard to change.  If there's some feature of Outlook/Exchange 2010 that would make this much easier compared to 2003, I can use the upgrade we just did as leverage...  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. I do not know enough about Exchange to help you with that. All I can tell you is it is extremely helpful to be able to see who is out of the office when I am trying to find someone.